# Audio Recognition Software, commercial detector?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audio-editing

I am wondering if there is such software or can be made. Every time a commercial is played on TV, few seconds before the commercial there is a signal like a beep.

I have links and when you paste them in browser they play an audio for 20-30 sec and I need to determine if that is a commercial.

Can some audio recognition software have for reference this beep signal that is playing before commercials, and go through all the links and mark the ones that have the beep(those are commercials)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically how easy it is depends on how consistent and "pure" the beep is - personally I would use the [Python](https://www.python.org/) programming language with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for downloading the files from the URLs. Then I would possibly use the [Python Audio Analysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis) library to see if the "beep" occurred in the first few seconds of each file.

All of the above are:

- Free (Gratis)
- Open Source
- Cross Platform, *(i.e. will run on just about anything).*
- Have a lot of community support